# Does returning a value in a Vuex action defeat the whole purpose of the Store?

Tags: vuex

Say I have an action like this:

```
  async getYoutubeReport({ commit }, payload) {
    return await this.$axios
      .get(
        `youtube/reports/${payload.date}/${payload.coin}`,
      ).then((res) => {
        let today = utils.yearMonthDay(new Date())
        let report = coinData.data.Items.find(Report => utils.yearMonthDay(new Date(Report.createdAt)) == today)

        commit('SET_YOUTUBE_REPORT', report)

        return report
      })
  }
}
```

Does this make any sense at all?

After all, the whole purpose of the Vuex Store is to horizontally make variables accesible across the app which can easily be done with reactive getters.

If the answer is "Yes, it is totally Fine", under which circumstances would make sense?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the only circumstance where I see it useful and where I do it is for showing a message response from the API in your Vue component.
If you need to access your state data you should use reactive getters.
Otherwise, there is no reason to maintain a vuex store and use data returned from your API.